# Extjs superboxselect keyup event is not firing

Tags: extjs, keyup

I am using superboxselect for one of my projects. I need to perform some additional filtering. Therefore i need to be able to do it in the keyup event.
But i can not get it to work.

```
 var test = new Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect( {
    applyTo : 'testId',
    id : 'test',
    allowBlank : true,
    msgTarget : 'title',
    xtype : 'superboxselect',
    resizable : true,
    hiddenName : 'statesHidden[]',
    width : 300,
    store : somestore,
    mode : 'local',
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField : 'code',
    classField : 'cls',
    styleField : 'style',
    extraItemCls : 'x-flag',
    extraItemStyle : 'border-width:2px',
    stackItems : true,
    listeners : {'keyup' : testFunction}
});

  function testFunction(){
       alert("hola");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

set enableKeyEvents property as true.

enableKeyEvents: true